# iOS device as an iBeacon, why is it not working?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral, cbperipheralmanager

I'm trying to make an iOS app that uses PeripheralManager to broadcast an UUID to a Central.

I think my [permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNqlF.png) and [Capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zouq.png) are in order,
but i still cant find my beacon when i search for it with the central.

Is there something i forgot?

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

var localBeacon: CLBeaconRegion!
var beaconPeripheralData: NSDictionary!
var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initLocalBeacon()

}

func initLocalBeacon() {

    if localBeacon != nil {
        stopLocalBeacon()
    }

    let localBeaconUUID = "e276c0c0-d740-52e8-b778-9ae6e514269e"
    let localBeaconMajor: CLBeaconMajorValue = 1
    let localBeaconMinor: CLBeaconMinorValue = 1

    let uuid = UUID(uuidString: localBeaconUUID)!
    localBeacon = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: localBeaconMajor, minor: localBeaconMinor, identifier: "Kristers Beacon")

    beaconPeripheralData = localBeacon.peripheralData(withMeasuredPower: -45)

    peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)


}

func stopLocalBeacon() {

    peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
    peripheralManager = nil
    beaconPeripheralData = nil
    localBeacon = nil
}

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {


    if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
        peripheralManager.startAdvertising(beaconPeripheralData as! [String: AnyObject]!)

    } else if peripheral.state == .poweredOff {
        stopLocalBeacon()
    }
}


}
```

Comment: You can't discover an iBeacon using `CBCentralManager`; you need to use CoreLocation and monitor a `CLBeaconRegion`

Comment: i'm not using CBCentralManager, but HW that runs as central with an C++ bluetooth scanner.

Comment: Then that is the code you probably need to show. The code you have shown here looks ok. Have you tried a beacon scanner from the App Store or similar on another device to check that it can see your beacon?  Have you tried  a beacon app from the App Store to confirm that your central can see a beacon from that app?

Comment: Also, I noticed that you have added background peripheral permission to your app. An iOS app can not advertise a beacon when it is in the background. Are you testing with your app in the foreground?

Comment: I tested your code and Radius Networks *Locate Beacon* app from the app store could discover it without an issue.  I would suggest that you declare `beaconPeripheralData` as `[String:Any]?` and say `beaconPeripheralData = localBeacon.peripheralData(withMeasuredPower: -45) as? [String:Any]` rather than the ugly force downcasts when you start advertising, but the code works both ways.

Comment: Ok, so you are getting the UUID and the identifier listed in this app?

Comment: Yes. I cut and pasted your code and then told *Locate Beacon* to look for that uuid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Bluetooth scanner, it did not search for the specific Proximity UUID. The *Locate beacon app* is great , thanks [paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11)